# Search AD SchemaClassName using DirectorySearcher

Tags: c#, .net, search, active-directory

Following is my implementation to do `AD` search.

```
DirectoryEntry de = GetDirectoryEntry();
using (var Search = new DirectorySearcher(de))
{ 
   Search.Filter = "....";
   Search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Name");
   Search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
   Search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectGUID");
   var results = Search.FindAll();
   //read properties here...     
   DirectoryEntry  resultde = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
    string schClassName = resultde.SchemaClassName;   //want to add SchemaClassName to PropertiesToLoad



}
```

I have been able to add `name`,`distinguishedName` and `objectGUID` to `DirectorySearcher`'s `PropertiesToLoad`. I also want to read value of `SchemaClassName`. Right now I have to call `GetDirectoryEntry` method to read it.  Is it possible to add `DirectorySearcher.SchemaClassName` to `PropertiesToLoad` rather than calling `GetDirectoryEntry` method? Is there any other better option to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `objectClass` attribute.

However, that attribute is a multi-value attribute that not only contains the class of the object, but the superclasses. So a user object will contain the values `top`, `person`, `organizationalPerson`, and `user`.

So if you're looking for the most specific class of the object, look at the last value. For example:

```
result.Properties["objectClass"][result.Properties["objectClass"].Count - 1]
```

More reading: [Object Class and Object Category](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/object-class-and-object-category)

On a side note, make sure to put `Search.FindAll()` in a `using` statement. In the [Remarks section of the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#remarks) it says:

> Due to implementation restrictions, the SearchResultCollection class cannot release all of its unmanaged resources when it is garbage collected. To prevent a memory leak, you must call the Dispose method when the SearchResultCollection object is no longer needed.

So it's more important to dispose of that than to dispose of the `DirectorySearcher`.